# Two Strings, the same type, one has "toInt" method, the other doesn't

Tags: scala

I have following code:

```
val nodePortString: scala.Predef.String = List.fromArray(args, 0, args.length).toList.headOption.getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException())
val a: scala.Predef.String = "1234" 
val b = a.toInt
val nodePort = nodePortString.toInt
```

I even added explicit types, with package, to be sure. The error is thrown from last line:

```
[error] /Users/amorfis/idea-workspace/akka-journal-stress/src/main/scala/core/core.scala:29: value toInt is not a member of String
[error]   val nodePort = nodePortString.toInt
[error]                                 ^
```

How on Earth is it possible, that I have 2 Strings, of exactly the same type, and one of them has "toInt" method, while the other hasn't?

It's on Scala 2.10.4

Comment: what's `List`? `scala.collection.immutable.List` doesn't have have a `fromArray` method

Comment: It does. It's deprecated, but it's there (at least in Scala 2.10.4).

Comment: Oh I see, I was looking at 2.11.2 docs

Answer (score 3):

`scala.Predef.String` is an alias for `java.lang.String`, which doesn't have a `toInt` method.

The reason why it normally works is that `String` is implicitly converted to `StringOps`, which provides all the scala niceties to the java type.

For some reason the implicit is not triggering and my hypothesis is that using the `fromArray` (deprecated) method messes up the types (arrays are funny beasts, due to java compabitility)

Can you try using

```
val nodePortString = args.toList.headOption.getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException())
```

instead?

---

### Update

I tested it on scala 2.10.4 and it compiles for me, here's a REPL session:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> object Main extends App {
     |   override def main(args: Array[String]) = {
     |     val nodePortString: scala.Predef.String = List.fromArray(args, 0, args.length).toList.headOption.getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException())
     |     val nodePort = nodePortString.toInt
     |   }
     | }
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
defined module Main
```

I assumed `args` to be the parameter of the `main` method of `App`, but it shouldn't make a difference as long as it's an `Array[String]`. Is that your actual code? Can you show a reproducible self-contained example?

Comment: In Scala 2.10 you can't call .toList on an Array[] but you can do `args.view.headOption.getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException).toInt`
and it should do the trick

Comment: The deprecation messages suggests to use `toList` and the documentation shows a `toList` method on `Array`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Maybe it's because the second string is actually wrapped by an Option?

Comment: @kciesielski I tried it on scala 2.10.4 and it works, so what you're saying it's not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure that nodePortString has same value ?!
The method .toInt it's from StringLike e appears to us via implicit conversion.

What is the args's value ?!

I've tried here with val args = Array("1","2","3","4") and got nodePort: Int = 1 ...

Works fine, but you must to sure ...